# IOS keyboard enter selector

Tags: ios, uitextfield

On IOS where do i hook up a selector to the keyboards enter button?

Cheers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `UITextFieldDelegate`-Protocol and implement:

`-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField`

See the [UITextFieldDelegate Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html).

Comment: Awesome, thank you. But how do i hide the keypad once its pressed.

Answer (score 4):

In the textFieldShouldReturn method listed by Till, you would do

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

to hide the keyboard.

Comment: Actually, UIView has the method endEditing:, which searches for the current responder and resigns it. This would probably be easier than figuring out which field has first responder and resigning it.

Comment: @PerishableDave - You don't have to figure out which field. In Till's example, the current first responder is set to textField.

Answer (score 1):

Add UITextFieldDelegate to your .h and add bellow code to your .m:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
};
```